# Isolate x in the equation

Tags: summation

I'm trying to isolate $x$ from the next equation. Some ideas?

\begin{equation}
k_{1} = k_{2}\sum_{i=1}^{x}\binom{x-1}{i-1}\frac{1}{i^{k_{3}}},
\end{equation}

where $k_{1}$, $k_{2}$ and $k_{3}$ are constants. If not possible to do it exactly, an approximation can also be used.

Thank you in advance by your help!

Comment: You are unlikely to get a closed form except in the simplest cases. If you have a less simple case I would use software.

Comment: Thank you @almagest. The simplest case for my problem is when k3 is a positive integer. greater than 2.

Answer (score 5):

**Forgive me as this is not entirely an answer** (I do not have comment privileges) but by observing only 
$$f(c)=\sum_{i=1}^x\binom{x-1}{i-1} \dfrac{1}{i^c}:c\in\mathbb{Z}$$

we can make some observations. Of course, in your case, $k_3\in\mathbb{R}$

I have listed some observations with various integer values below:

\begin{align}
&\quad\!\!\!\cdot\\
&\quad\!\!\!\cdot\\
&\quad\!\!\!\cdot\\
f(-3)&=(x+1)(x^2+5x-2)2^{x-4}\\
f(-2)&=x(x+3)2^{x-3}\\
f(-1)&=(x+1)2^{x-2}\\
f(0)&=2^{x-1}\\
f(1)&=\frac{2^{x-1}}{x}\\
f(2)&=_3\!\!F_2(1,1,1-x;2,2;-1)\\
f(3)&=_4\!\!F_3(1,1,1,1-x;2,2,2;-1)\\
&\quad\!\!\!\cdot\\
&\quad\!\!\!\cdot\\
&\quad\!\!\!\cdot\\
\end{align}

where $_pF_q(a_1,\cdots,a_p;b_1,\cdots,b_q;x)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function given by
 $$_pF_q(a_1,\cdots,a_p;b_1,\cdots,b_q;x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(a_1)_k\cdots(a_p)_kx^k}{(b_1)_k\cdots(b_q)_kk!}$$

We do notice some behavior with the function $f(c)$ as the polynomial "coefficient" decreases its degree by 1 with on increase of $c$ by $1$ and the exponent power increases by $1$ up until $f(0)$.

In general for $c=k_3\in\mathbb{Z^{>2}}$,

$$f(c)=_{c+1}F_{c}(\underbrace{1,\cdots,1}_{c+1 \quad\!\!\! \text{times}},1-x;\underbrace{2,\cdots 2}_{c \quad\!\!\! \text{times}};-1)$$

Comment: Thank you by your help Hannah!

Comment: Looking at your comment reply to almagest, I believe your best bet is by looking at the generalized hypergeometric function. I will edit my post to adjust my answer to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Hannah, you are great! Is it possible to isolate x from f(c)? For now I have no privileges to give +1 to your answer, sorry for that!

Comment: A closed-form is highly unlikely. Sorry!